# Dynamic target for root or nested directory

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

My makefile contains a target for `node_modules` directory, which depends on `package.json` file:

```
node_modules: package.json
    npm install && touch "$@"
```

My current project happens to have a "sub-package" with its own set of dependencies. I modify the target above to the following:

```
%/node_modules: %/package.json
    cd $(shell dirname "$<") && npm install && touch node_modules
```

Now, I can do `make path/to/subpackage/node_modules` and `make` runs the expected `npm install` command. However, I no longer seem to be able to do `make node_modules` - `make` exits with status code `0` and message *Nothing to be done for 'node_modules'.*

This indicates `make` will now only run the appropriate command for *node_modules* folders which exist within a subdirectory.

**How can I change the target so that it supports both nested and root `node_modules` directories within the same target?**

In other words, I would like to remove the duplicated target definition because the command to make the root's *node_modules* directory is the same as the command to make the nested *path/to/node_modules* directory.

> As research, I tried to look at the [GNU Make tutorial](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/make_4.html) but could not find any relevant information - possibly because I simply do not know what to look for.

Comment: `make ./node_modules` would probably accomplish what you want if I understand you correctly.

Comment: As an aside, `$*` contains the part which matched `%` so calling `$(shell dirname "$<")` is pretty excessive.

Comment: To quote [the GNUmake manual 10.5.1](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html#Pattern-Intro) "the ‘%’ matches any nonempty substring". Therefore, `%/node_modules` will never match `/node_modules` and even less `node_modules`. I can imagine that the caveat of `%` _not matching the empty string_ in patterns is preventing a lot of bad things in other places, so I think its there with a reason.

Comment: I tried to use `make ./node_modules` as well, but `make` does not run the expected target for this path (same behaviour as `make node_modules`). I can, however, run `make $(pwd)/node_modules` from the current working directory. This is not ideal, however, since I have other targets which depend on *node_modules*.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't very elegant, but you could use a ["canned recipe"](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Canned-Recipes):

```
define MAKE_NODE_MODULES
npm install && touch node_modules
endef

node_modules: package.json
    $(MAKE_NODE_MODULES)

%/node_modules: %/package.json
    cd $* && $(MAKE_NODE_MODULES)
```